# cakephp Cannot use string offset as an array

Tags: arrays, cakephp, view

hi all in my view I'm getting this error when trying to print out information in my array.

here is my function in the controller

```
public function view($name)
$fields = $this->Template->Field->find('list',array( 
          'fields'=> array('name'),
          'conditions' => array(
          'template_id'=> $name)));
$this->set('field', $fields);
```

here is the view

```
</br><h2>Here is your template fields</h2></br>

            <?php if(!empty($field))
                  {
                    foreach($field as $name)
                    {?>
                        <tr>
                        <td>
                        <?php echo $name['Field']['name']; ?>
                        </tr></br>
                        <?php
            }
            }
            else
            {?>
             <tr> <td>No Templates Found.</td></tr>
             <?php 
             }?>
```

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in relation to this line   <?php echo $name['Field']['name']; ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I already answer some of your questions. So what I understood about your project is "Template hasMany Fields" and you already defined an association-ship in the corresponding models.

You should use the following code into your view:

```
<?php if(!empty($field))
              {
                foreach($field as $name)
                {?>
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                    <?php echo $name; ?>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
        }
        }
        else
        {?>
         <tr> <td>No Template Fields Found.</td></tr>
         <?php 
         }?>
```

Comment: it is going straight to the else statement :/

Comment: Array
(
    [1] => amount
    [2] => description
    [3] => totalacctowing
    [4] => pmtinfo
)

list of field names

Comment: it prints it out in a horizontal line but i need to access other information to do with those fields and can't access them without ['field']['id'] aswell

Comment: no, because if i try print out the information related to that input it goes straight to else

Comment: If there is no result for any template, then it will always lie in else condition. Check your query.

Comment: i needed to change the find query from list to all

Answer (score 0):

you have operation with type list so the result will be an array in [field.id] => [field.name]

then you will require following in view

```
<?php foreach($field as $name): ?>
<?= $name ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```